# How to automatically check mark a box in one googles spread sheet, when clicking a button on another google spread sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox

I have a spreadsheet that has a button for approval, this button will send out an email saying it was approved. I want this same button to automatically check mark another spreadsheet.
This is what I have for the button approval/email. I am working on the check mark but it's not working.

```
function showMessageBox() {
Browser.msgBox('Your PO has been approved!');
 // Fetch the email address
var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("C7");
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();

// Send Alert Email.
var message = 'This PO has been approved!'; // Second column
var subject = 'Your PO request has been approved';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}

function showMessageBox2() {
  Browser.msgBox('Your PO has been rejeced! We need more info');
 // Fetch the email address
var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("C7");
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();

// Send Alert Email.
var message = 'This PO has been rejected, we need more information!'; // Second column
var subject = 'Your PO request has been rejected';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

Comment: If you already have the [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) where the checkbox is located you can use the [check()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#check) function, like: `checkbox.check()`. I could provide a more complete answer if you share what you've worked on and why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you already have a working button script and want to extend its function to toggle a checkbox in a different Sheet. If my understanding of your scenario is correct, then you can reach your goal in two simple steps. First you need to locate the checkbox in your script, you can do so using the same approach as you used on the email range:

```js
var checkbox = SpreadsheetApp.openById("{ SHEET ID }").getSheetByName("My Sheet").getRange(6,6);
```

Then you only have to toggle the checkbox with [`Range.check()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#check):

```
checkbox.check();
```